# How to completely delete 'Install MacOS Catalina'?

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

I am still on macOS Mojave and I don't want for the time being to upgrade to Catalina but the OS automatically downloads an installer for Catalina called 'Install MacOS Catalina' which is listed in the apps. This takes 8GB of space and I need this space.

The problem is that if I delete it, the system downloads it again automatically (for some reason the second time 16GB are missing!)

How can I remove this completely and prevent it from being downloaded again? I really want to download and install Catalina when I am ready(from Software Update). Since then I need the disk space.

Comment: In Software Update → Advanced…, is the option to automatically download, or to install macOS updates, checked?

Comment: @ChrisWarrick No it is unckecked

Comment: Then it is already downloaded. If it isn't in your /Applications folder look in /Library/Updates and remove it from there. Once it is gone and you have turned off automatic updates all you will see is the *option* to download/install. Unfortunately Apple removed the hidden switch to turn off OS upgrade notifications so you are stuck with that little red dot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same (or a similar) issue. I found the solution [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection) and [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/cant-delete-catalina-install-file.2254150/), but will briefly recap the steps below.

1. Restart in recovery mode (click Apple logo then Restart, right after that press Command + R).
2. In recovery mode, select the "Utilities" dropdown (upper left) and select "Terminal".
3. Type `csrutil disable`.
4. Restart.
5. If the Catalina install app (or whichever file) is in the trash, simply empty it. If it needs to be moved there first do that then empty trash.
6. Restart in recovery mode (click Apple logo then Restart, right after that press Command + R).
7. In recovery mode select the "Utilities" dropdown (upper left) and select "Terminal"
8. Type `csrutil enable`.
9. Restart